# implementation of ckeditor in an html page

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

I have downloaded the CKeditor. But I don't know how it implements in my html form. Does any one know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the manual? [Installation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Installation)

then theres the **_samples/index.html** once you have unziped the package